# WPF/XAML doesn't look like system theme

Tags: c#, wpf

I would expect a default project for WPF to use the exact system theme, but the default theme for WPF looks somewhat akin to Windows 10, but not quite. And rather ugly if I had my opinion. My question is - how do I make WPF follow system theme?

Screenshot below is running in Windows 11. It's just a deafult project using File > New Project > WPF Application

[image: Image showing WPF]

This screenshot is from some random Visual Studio menu. Obviously these buttons look much different.

[image]

Comment: do you want to look like win10 even if you are running on win7?

Comment: @LeiYang no, I want them to look like whatever version of Windows they're running on.

Comment: that's interesting. but i heared wpf is device independent...

Comment: Why do you think VS uses default theme? Why do you think another apps use default theme?

Comment: @Rekshino because when I updated the system from Windows 10 to Windows 11, all applications that used to look like Windows 10 now look like Windows 11, but without updating any applications...

Comment: @AlgoRythm This only works for `WinForms` and doesn't work for `WPF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would expect a default project for WPF to use the exact system theme ...

I am afraid your expectation is wrong. The default WPF templates have not been updated for Windows 11 and I strongly doubt they ever will be.

If you want a modern UI experience in your Windows apps, I would recommend you to look into using [WinUI](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml) (3). It's the the next generation native UI layer for Windows, including full-trust desktop apps.

Comment: Honestly ((WINDOWS)) presentation foundation not following Windows look and feel by default seems like such an awful decision that I never even considered it. Maybe they'll finally get things right with WinUI.

Comment: Not only has it not been updated for Windows 11 and 10, it already didn't really match Windows 8. I have a larger application and use several OS-specific themes to try and adapt to the environment. But it's hard to retheme WPF controls. They allow it but it causes truckloads of work. So it uses a bad design for this feature. You might be better off saying goodbye to the native theme and use something (modern) else instead, regardless the Windows version.

Comment: To view the WinUI 3 controls in an interactive format, check out `WinUI 3 Controls Gallery` app from the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/p/winui-3-controls-gallery/9p3jfpwwdzrc) or get the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/tree/winui3):

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you will get to this is by using [ModernWPF](https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf).

This is basically a port of WinUI to WPF, but only up until WinUI 2.6 when Microsoft introduced the Windows 11 styles. The project currently has open issues logged for Windows 11 styles but it's still up in the air as for whether it'll gain support for these anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

There's a WinUI 3 port for WPF called [WPFUI](https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui). It requires some simple steps to modernize your WPF application and make it look like Windows 11 new UI (Unlike XAML Island where you have to do dozens of steps and still need to change your UI codes and create another project in the solution)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question, but I suspect that you just want to make the appearance more attractive.

To do this, you can use the style libraries. For example here. I used it myself for applications. Very easy to learn:

https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

And here. I haven't used it, but it looks interesting:

https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/